# How do I format numbers to have only two decimal places?

Tags: php, mysql

I want that real numbers would be for example 12.92, but not 12.9241. Is it possible to do like that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In PHP, try **[`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)**:

```
$n = 1234.5678;

// Two decimal places, using '.' for the decimal separator
// and ',' for the thousands separator.
$formatted = number_format($n, 2, '.', ',');
// 1,234.57
```

Answer (score 4):

For PHP you can use `number_format()`, for MySQL use the `FORMAT()` function.

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format

```
FORMAT(number, 2)
```

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
       -> '12,332.1235
```

PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
$number = 1234.5678;
$formatted_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.56
```

Comment: You can also use ROUND() in the same fashion if you don't want the thousands delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

```
$number = 1234.5678;
$teX = explode('.', $number);

if(isset($teX[1])){
    $de = substr($teX[1], 0, 2);
    $final = $teX[0].'.'.$de;
    $final = (float) $final;
}else{
    $final = $number;   
}
```

final will be 1234.56

Answer (score -1):

You can multiply your number by 100, do a rounding of the result and then divide back by 100.

Or in php use the round function [round function](http://www.manuelphp.com/php/function.round.php)

```
$result=round(12.9241, 2);
```