# How can I format the number for only showing 1 decimal place in php?

Tags: php

Does any one know how can I format the number and limited it to only show 1 decimal place in php?

Example:

How can I format the number 2.10 to 2.1 in php?

Comment: A duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992406/how-do-i-format-numbers-to-have-only-two-decimal-places

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use PHP's `number_format`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Example:

`$one_decimal_place = number_format(2.10, 1);`

If you ever need to convert it back to a float:

`$the_float_value = floatval($one_decimal_place);`

Also, [this](http://www.elated.com/articles/php-number-format/) article is a good reference for different decimal characters and separator styles.

Comment: Remove the quotes around the first argument. The first arg is a float, not a string.

Comment: it corrects only in case of 2.10 but if the value is 2.98 then it will convert it into 3.0 so this is not the right answer

here is the right answer

echo bcdiv(5.98735, 1, 1);  // 5.9
echo bcdiv(5.98735, 1, 2);  // 5.98

Answer (score 9):

You use the round function

```
echo round(3.4445, 1); // 3.4
```

Comment: Doesn't turn full integer numbers (`3`) into (`3.0`). Instead you get `3`

Answer (score 4):

Number format will do this for you.

```
$num = 2.10;
number_format($num, 1);
```

[PHP: number_format](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)
with a precision of 1, but note that some people see longer than expected result. You can also use [printf()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)
or [sprintf()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)
with a format of `"%.1f"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP native function [bcdiv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

```
echo bcdiv(5.98735, 1, 1);  // 5.9
echo bcdiv(5.98735, 1, 2);  // 5.98
echo bcdiv(5.98735, 1, 3);  // 5.987
echo bcdiv(-5.98735, 1, 1); // -5.9
echo bcdiv(-5.98735, 1, 2); // -5.98
echo bcdiv(-5.98735, 1, 3); // -5.987
```

Comment: "bcdiv — Divide two arbitrary precision numbers", bit of an overkill to always divide the value by one ($num2 = divisor)  just to use the 3th var

Answer (score 0):

Use `number_format` function. `number_format("2.10", 1)` will simply do that. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is the documentation.