# How to echo number format like this using php?

Tags: php

How to echo number format like this using php  ?

```
0.50 echo to 0.5
1.00 echo to 1
1.50 echo to 1.5
1.95 echo to 1.95
```

I tried to use `number_format` , `ceil` , `floor` , `round` But not work.

How can i do that ?

Thank you for help.

Comment: `echo number_format(0.50, 1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format the number for only showing 1 decimal place in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622328/how-can-i-format-the-number-for-only-showing-1-decimal-place-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `floatval` function instead like as

```
echo floatval(0.50);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/462671)

Comment: you can also use typecasting instead of functions: `(float) $value;`. This is little faster than `floatval($value)`

Comment: Yes you're right but than can be the tedious task to place it all over those strings @ling.s

Answer (score 1):

It's really silly, but you can simply `add 0` to get this effect.

```
echo "0.50" + 0;
echo "1.00" + 0;
```

[Example](https://eval.in/462664)

Comment: You can find the above answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531679/remove-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals-in-php

Answer (score 1):

This can do a trick:

```
<?php 
$string = "1.50";
echo (float)$string;
?>
```

This gives

> 1.5

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this :

```
echo +'1.00';
echo +'0.50';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
<?php 
$data = "1.00";    
$arr = explode(".",$data);
$formated_nunber=formatNumber($arr);


function formatNumber($arr){
    if($arr[1]==00){ 
      $finalStr=$arr[0];
      return $finalStr;
}
else if(substr($arr[1],-1)==0){
    $arr[1]=rtrim($arr[1],substr($arr[1],-1));
    $finalStr=implode(".",$arr);
    return $finalStr;
}else{
    $finalStr=implode(".",$arr);
    return $finalStr;
}
}   
echo "<pre>";print_r($formated_nunber);
//echo $whatIWant;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `number_format(0.50, 1)`. That will do the trick.

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as answers that have working code plus helpful explanations. 
In this case, it would be worthwhile explaining this answer to a 5 year old.