# Delete digits after two decimal points, without rounding the value

Tags: php, function, rounding

i have value in php variable like that

```
$var='2.500000550';
echo $var
```

what i want is to delete all decimal points after 2 digits.

like now value of variable will be

```
$var='2.50';
echo $var
```

> keep in mind this value is coming from mysql databse

but when i use `round php function` i got round but i dont need round, i just need to delete all digits after 2 decimal simple.

i have tired, `flot()` and lot of other option no success.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried number_format?

Comment: It's not explicitly documented, but **number_format** rounds.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

## TL;DR:

The PHP native function [bcdiv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php) seems to do precisely what is required, and properly.

To simply "truncate" a number, `bcdiv($var, 1, 2);` where 2 is the number of decimals to preserve (and 1 is the denomenator - dividing the number by 1 allows you to simply truncate the original number to the desired decimal places)

## Full Answer (for history)

This turns out to be more elusive than one might think.

After this answer was (incorrectly) upvoted quite a bit, it has come to my attention that even sprintf will round.

Rather than delete this answer, I'm turning it into a more robust explanation / discussion of each proposed solution.

**number_format - Incorrect. (rounds)**
Try using [number format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$var = number_format($var, 2, '.', '');  // Last two parameters are optional
echo $var;
// Outputs 2.50
```

If you want it to be a number, then simply type-cast to a float:

```
$var = (float)number_format($var, 2, '.', '');
```

**Note:** as has been pointed out in the comments, this does in fact *round* the number.

**sprintf - incorrect. (sprintf also rounds)**
If not rounding the number is important, then per the answer below, use [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$var = sprintf("%01.2f", $var);
```

**floor - not quite! (floor rounds negative numbers)**

[floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php), with some math, will come close to doing what you want:

```
floor(2.56789 * 100) / 100; // 2.56
```

Where 100 represents the precision you want.  If you wanted it to three digits, then:

```
floor(2.56789 * 1000) / 1000; // 2.567
```

However, this has a problem with negative numbers.  Negative numbers still get rounded, rather than truncated:

```
floor(-2.56789 * 100) / 100; // -2.57
```

## "Old" Correct answer: function utilizing floor

So a fully robust solution requires a function:

```
function truncate_number( $number, $precision = 2) {
    // Zero causes issues, and no need to truncate
    if ( 0 == (int)$number ) {
        return $number;
    }
    // Are we negative?
    $negative = $number / abs($number);
    // Cast the number to a positive to solve rounding
    $number = abs($number);
    // Calculate precision number for dividing / multiplying
    $precision = pow(10, $precision);
    // Run the math, re-applying the negative value to ensure returns correctly negative / positive
    return floor( $number * $precision ) / $precision * $negative;
}
```

Results from the above function:

```
echo truncate_number(2.56789, 1); // 2.5
echo truncate_number(2.56789);    // 2.56
echo truncate_number(2.56789, 3); // 2.567

echo truncate_number(-2.56789, 1); // -2.5
echo truncate_number(-2.56789);    // -2.56
echo truncate_number(-2.56789, 3); // -2.567
```

## New Correct Answer

Use the PHP native function [bcdiv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

```
echo bcdiv(2.56789, 1, 1);  // 2.5
echo bcdiv(2.56789, 1, 2);  // 2.56
echo bcdiv(2.56789, 1, 3);  // 2.567
echo bcdiv(-2.56789, 1, 1); // -2.5
echo bcdiv(-2.56789, 1, 2); // -2.56
echo bcdiv(-2.56789, 1, 3); // -2.567
```

Comment: it should maybe be mentioned that number_format returns a string and not a number.

Comment: sprintf _does_ round, though. `sprintf("%01.2f", 2.509) != '2.50'`. -1 sorry.

Comment: -1 removed. No +1 though as still not quite right - try this for 2.05. :-)  You need to factor in an epsilon to account for float storage irregularities - refer @David Constantine's answer (and now, mine!).

Comment: I used this and it's works: bcdiv($price,1,2); But this one too: floor(2.56789 * 100) / 100; // 2.56

Comment: @WilliamRossier - `bcdiv` is the right answer.  `floor` has a problem with negative numbers, so is not correct.  Nice tip!

Comment: @Reado - can you expand / clarify how bcdiv is incorrect? I'd like to know / correct the answer.

Comment: BEWARE! a zero should not be passed to truncate_number as $number

Comment: @MuhammadAtif - yes, that's not the correct answer in this post.  The correct answer is `bcdiv`

Comment: By the way, bcadd($num_FLO, 0, $prec_INT) is preffered if you only need to delete digits because it's working faster that div or mul operations)

Comment: So close.  This:
    `if ( 0 == (int)$number ) {
        return $number;
    }`
Should be
`if ( (int)$number == 0 ) {
        return $number;
    }`

Just a bit backwards.  Thanks for the function.

Comment: @Bill_VA - thanks for the comment.  Actually, my code is correct (as is yours), and mine follows a "defensive" coding pattern known [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).  If you forget one of the `=` symbols in _your_ code, you get an unintentional assignment of `0` to the `$number` variable.  If you forget one of the `=` symbols in _my_ code, you get an error, and the PHP won't run.

Comment: With `bcdiv(0.20198302, 1, 2)` keep in mind this: `0.20` will be shown as `0.2`.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro - this is not about formatting a guaranteed number of decimal places, this is about **truncating** to a **maximum** number of decimal places, without rounding.  Therefore, your comment is "correct / expected" behavior.

Comment: floor doesn't work on numbers which are periodic in binary system, try it, for example 'floor(2.092484 * 1000000) / 1000000' => you get '2.092483'

Comment: @FantomX1 - Floor is not the answer.  It is included in my post only to demonstrate why it is _not_ the answer.  `bcdiv`, which is at the top and the bottom of my post, is the correct answer.

Comment: Absolute the best answer on the net so far typeof() says it is a double too!

Comment: what about `bcmul`? will it give the same results as `bcdiv` in this case?

Answer (score 13):

```
floor(2.500000550 * 100) / 100;
```

This should do your task...

Comment: This is the simplest method.  number_format still rounds the result.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer IMHO, @air.  All other answers round prior to truncation, such that the rounding is only evident when it results in increment of the last desired (in this case, 2nd) decimal place.  This solution avoids that by effectively moving the decimal point two places right (by multiplying by 100), truncating (using floor), then moving it back 2 places left (divide by 100).  Genius in its simplicity.

Comment: @Sepster - actually, this has an issue with rounding negative numbers.  I've improved my answer to address even that scenario.

Comment: Good pickup, @cale_b!

Comment: This could also very easily be turned into a function where you can input the amount of decimals you'd like to see as well.

Answer (score 6):

You're requesting a function that returns `"2.50"` and not `2.5`, so *you aren't talking about arithmetic* here but **string manipulation**. Then `preg_replace` is your friend:

```
$truncatedVar = preg_replace('/\.(\d{2}).*/', '.$1', $var);

// "2.500000050" -> "2.50", "2.509" -> "2.50", "-2.509" -> "2.50", "2.5" -> "2.5"
```

If you want to do it with arithmetic, simply use:

```
$truncatedVar = round($var * 100) / 100);

// "2.500000050" -> "2.5", "2.599" -> "2.59", "-2.599" -> "2.59"
```

Comment: doesn't work on numbers which are periodic in binary system, try it, for example 'intval(2.092484 * 1000000) / 1000000' => you get '2.092483' , however yours string minupulation with preg_replace works very well, big up from me, thank you

Comment: @FantomX1 You're absolutely right. If I wanted to be a nitpicker I'd say that the OP asked for two digits and `'intval(2.092484 * 100) / 100' is `2.09` but I think using `round` instead of `intval` should make this more bulletproof. Thanks!

Comment: good point with two decimals, me personally needed 6 though, round removes periodic number infinite sequence that's true, but you don't always want to round like for example me when I compare data against remote system, where mysql column does exactly what your string replace, just cuts off from a specific ordinal digit  I want to have always returned 2.09 no matter if its 2.094 or 2.096, therefore round is of no use for me, but preg replace works

Comment: How about `preg_replace('/\.\d{2}\K\d+', '', $var)` instead?

Answer (score 4):

try with [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format('2.50000050', 2); // 2.50
```

Comment: This is rounds, then truncates. So if the input number was 2.509 then the above will return 2.51, not 2.50. So does not answer the question that explicitly states "not round"

Comment: Also he asked how to delete, you are still keeping the fraction

Answer (score 4):

number_format rounds the number

```
php > echo number_format(128.20512820513, 2)."\n";
128.21
```

I used preg_replace to really cut the string

```
php > echo preg_replace('/(\.\d\d).*/', '$1', 128.20512820513)."\n";
128.20
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the PHP native function [bcdiv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php).

**Example:**

```
echo bcdiv(3.22871, 1, 1);  // 3.2
echo bcdiv(3.22871, 1, 2);  // 3.22
echo bcdiv(3.22871, 1, 3);  // 3.228
echo bcdiv(-3.22871, 1, 1); // -3.2
echo bcdiv(-3.22871, 1, 2); // -3.22
```

For your case:

```
$var='2.500000550';
echo $var
echo bcdiv($var, 1, 2);  // 2.50
```

Answer (score 2):

someone posted here about

> floor(2.500000550 * 100) / 100;

```
function cutAfterDot($number, $afterDot = 2){
$a = $number * pow(10, $afterDot);
$b = floor($a);
$c = pow(10, $afterDot);
echo "a $a, b $b, c $c<br/>";
return $b/$c ;
}
echo cutAfterDot(2.05,2);

a 205, b 204, c 100
2.04
```

so in raw form don't use it...
But if you add a little epsilon...

```
function cutAfterDot($number, $afterDot = 2){
        return floor($number * pow(10, $afterDot) + 0.00001) / pow(10, $afterDot);
    }
```

it works!

Comment: An explanation as to why `floor(205)` is returning 204 here, can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php#114204

Comment: This actually will round negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
sprintf("%01.2f", $var);
```

Comment: This is rounds, then truncates.  So if `$var == 2.509` then the above will return 2.51, not 2.50.  So does not answer the question that explicitly states "not round".

Answer (score 1):

The following is (what I believe is - please correct me if not) a robust *mathematical** solution, based mostly on the information from several other answerers here, and a small amount from me

(*Which is not to suggest there's anything wrong with [Liphtier's regex-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19926354/1554982) - just that I can see purists wanting to avoid regex for what is arguably a mathematical problem.)

- `sprintf()`, `number_format()` (and `round()`, obviously), are all performing a rounding operation so are not appropriate for the non-rounding truncation requested in the question (not on their own, at least).
- In lieu of an out-of-the-box function, the seemingly most elegant solution was [Sujit Agarwal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9944040/1554982)
- But because of the way floats are stored, we need to use an epsilon - as pointed out in [David Constantine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12556531/1554982) (where he also makes the previous solution more general by using `pow()` to get the right factor based on a specified precision).
- But then, as pointed out in [cale_b's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9944052/1554982), any use of `floor()` (or presumably `ceil()`) may produce unintended results for negatives without use of `abs()`.
- And the value I'm trying to add is:

  - If using a division on `abs()` to get a negation factor, we need to account for the special case when the input is 0.
  - We should dynamically create the epsilon; A static hard-coded epsilon might be too small or too large, depending on the precision required.  I haven't seen this issue addressed in the other answers.

The code I'm using is:

```
public static function truncate_decimal($number, $leavePlaces = 2)
{
    if ($number == 0) return 0;
    $negate = $number / abs($number);
    $shiftFactor = pow(10, $leavePlaces);
    $epsilon = pow(10, -1 * $leavePlaces);
    return floor(abs($number) * $shiftFactor + $epsilon) / $shiftFactor * $negate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Already a lot of possible solutions, I just want to add the one that I came up to solve my problem.

```php
function truncate_decimals($number, $decimals=2)
{
  $factor = pow(10,$decimals); 
  $val = intval($number*$factor)/$factor;
  return $val;
}


truncate_decimals(199.9349,2);
// 199.93
```

Comment: Just tried it it is giving me, which seems correct.
truncate_decimals(10056468765.254564) => 10056468765.25

Comment: I'll investigate and I'll delete my previous comment. If I find steps to reproduce, ill post them here.

Answer (score 0):

All of the solutions which use number_format are wrong because number_format performs rounding.

The function below should work on all numbers, you can specify the decimal separator for those countries which use ','.

```
function truncate_decimal($number, $truncate_decimal_length = 2, $decimal_character = '.', $thousands_character = '') {

$number = explode($decimal_character, $number);
$number[1] = substr($number[1], 0, $truncate_decimal_length);
$number_truncated = implode($decimal_character, $number);
return number_format($number_truncated, $truncate_decimal_length, $decimal_character, $thousands_character);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to follow would be "If greater than 0 floor, else ceil", using a multiplier to raise it above the decimal point temporarily whilst doing it:

```
function trim_num($num_in, $dec_places = 2) {
    $multiplier = pow(10, $dec_places); // 10, 100, 1000, etc
    if ($num_in > 0) {
        $num_out = floor($num_in * $multiplier) / $multiplier;
    } else {
        $num_out = ceil($num_in * $multiplier) / $multiplier;
    }
    return $num_out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = 118.74999669307;
$cut = substr($num, 0, ((strpos($num, '.')+1)+2));
// Cut the string from first character to a length of 2 past the decimal.
// substr(cut what, start, ( (find position of decimal)+decimal itself)+spaces after decimal) )
echo $cut;
```

Answer (score 0):

> floor - not quite! (floor rounds negative numbers)

A possible solution from **cale_b** answer.

```
static public function rateFloor($rate, $decimals)
{

    $div = "1" . str_repeat("0", $decimals);

    if ($rate > 0) {
        return floor($rate * $div) / $div;
    }

    $return = floor(abs($rate) * $div) / $div;

    return -($return);

}
```

---

```
static public function rateCeil($rate, $decimals)
{

    $div = "1" . str_repeat("0", $decimals);

    if ($rate > 0) {
        return ceil($rate * $div) / $div;
    }

    $return = ceil(abs($rate) * $div) / $div;

    return -($return);

}
```

Positive

> Rate: 0.00302471
>
> Floor: 0.00302400
>
> Ceil: 0.00302500

Negative

> Rate: -0.00302471
>
> Floor: -0.00302400
>
> Ceil: -0.00302500

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to round the number but you want to remove the decimal places you can use "substr" method

```
substr(string, start, length);
substr(4.96, 0, -1);
```

Comment: This wont work with "2.500000550" as the value. You will get "2.50000055" as the result as per your solution.

Comment: You have to increase the length, substr(2.500000550, 0, -6); then you will get '2.50',

Comment: The data comes from a mysql database, so that should be dynamic