# Number format display in php

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am new to php. Can anyone tell how to change the query such that it will print 16.66. I need 16.66667 to be only 16.66.

```
    <?php
    $number = 16.6666667;
    $n = number_format($number, 2);
    echo $n; // 16.67    
?>
```

I am getting output as 16.67. Thanks for any help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944001/delete-digits-after-two-decimal-point-not-round-number-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$n = substr($number, 0, strrpos($number, '.') + 3);
```

**EDIT**

For any number with or without decimals, try this:

```
$n = number_format($number, 3);
$n = substr($n, 0, strrpos($n, '.') + 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```
$number=floor(16.6666667 * 100) / 100;
```

This will return value without rounding the number.

Comment: it is printing 16.67 only i need it to print 16.66

Comment: actually i am passing the number dynamically

Comment: what is the problem now? Give the variable name in place of number.

Comment: ya but it is giving 16.67 only

Comment: oh k i am sorry and thanks for your co-operation sister @jenz

Comment: If i have any doubt i will ask you here

Comment: @user3247641 actually if I am giving a number it is working fine..without seeing your code how can I tell whatz wrong..

Comment: which method you are following the first or second..the second one is the better solution. ie dividing by 100 method..let me know if you are getting the same problem even with the second method

Comment: No i used first method

Comment: my name is sandeep not user3247641

Comment: <?php
 $number = 16.666666; 
 $number = (float)number_format($number, 2, '.', ''); 
 echo $number;
?>   this is code i have cut and pasted it

Comment: i need oone more help in multiple box retrieving code

Comment: while retreiving the for multiple check box if there is only one data in database column then it will enable there but if we have one or more values then while retrieving it will not enable at all why how should we retrieve in multiple box

Comment: can you show me the code you have written so far for the checkbox only?

Comment: ya wait i will post another question and share the link with u

Comment: Sister this is the issue which i am facing please  help me in solving the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479071/multiple-box-has-a-issue-which-i-am-not-able-to-solve

Comment: please send your skype id or send a request to sandeepv0428@gmail.com or my skype name is sandeepv28 i am from bangalore . i need u sister Jenz