# multiple box has a issue which i am not able to solve

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am retrieving the data from database using multiple box which i have created below code it looks like this

```
     project_maker
  |------------------------|
  |  Deepak                |
  |  Arun                  |                      
  |  vinay                 |
  |  Piyush                |
  |  Madhuri               |
  |  Deep                  |
  |------------------------|
```

When i retrieve any row from data and if it has more than one project_maker then multiple box will not enable any names in above box but if there is only one name then it enables.
how to enable if there are two names in database and enable automatically.

if u didn't understand i will give an example in one row there will be deepak,Arun in database but while retrieving using select query mention below . It must get highlighted to particular names for deepak and arun but none of the names are highlighted in multiple check box

I can insert multiple data using multiple box while retrieving it wont get highlighted if there are two names

The code which i have used 
this code is for back end

```
$pid = $_POST['project'];



    $result = mysql_query("select project_name,  project_code, projects_makers from projects where project_code = '$pid'") or die(mysql_error());$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        $mak_arr = explode(",",$r['projects_makers']); //project_markers has only id numbers 
        $mak_names = "";
        foreach($mak_arr as $mak)
        {
            $send = mysql_query("select project_name from users where id = '$pid'") or die(mysql_error()); // to get there names as per the id i am using this query
            list($mak_name) = mysql_fetch_array($send);
            $mak_names .= $mak_name."<br>";
        }   
        echo json_encode($r);  }
```

This code belongs to front end i have created multiple box

```
$result_maker = mysql_query("select id,project_maker from users where account_type = 'Maker' order by name");<label>Project Maker:</label><select class="textbox" name="project_makers[]" multiple="multiple" style="height:200px" id="project_makers"><option value="">Select</option>
<?php while(list($id,$project_maker) = mysql_fetch_array($result_maker)) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $project_maker; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select><br />
```

This is the projects table database data

```
| project_code | project_name | project_maker |  team_size |
|    56        | cisco system |  1,5,6,9,14   |      5     |
```

This is users database data

```
| id | account_type |  name   | 
| 1  |    Maker     |  Deepak |
| 5  |    Maker     |  Arun   |
| 6  |    Maker     |  Vinay  |
| 9  |    Maker     | Madhuri |
| 14 |    Maker     |  Deep   |
```

Only this 5 name must highlight or enable while retrieving in above multiple box

Comment: for starters....`mysql_query` is stone age, use `mysqli_query` or `PDO`...

Comment: will it work and what all i must change if i use mysqli

Comment: It will work but it is depreciated . You can read about mysqli here http://in1.php.net/mysqli

Comment: @Sandeep : search `php manuals` for `mysqli_`....Also, your question is highly unclear....mind rephrasing that what is the condition on which `higlighting` the name should work??is it for particular name or some other parameter?

Comment: @Let'sCode It's *deprecated* - which may or may not adversely affect its inherent value.

Comment: mysqli on its own will not be enough. You should not expose your database to raw data in this way. Also see prepared statements.

Comment: Actually I am not clear with the code..Can you share the required database table structure.

Comment: ya sure i will paste the database data

Comment: hey sister see i have edited my code and i have put the database structure @Jenz

Comment: does anyone know how to solve this please