# Displaying two digits after decimal point mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a field in a mysql table, the field name is menu_price. The value of menu_price is displayed as `50.000`. 
However i want this value to be `50.00` instead of `50.000`.
 My client does not want to show the price as `50.000`. So i need to change it to `50.00`.

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944001/delete-digits-after-two-decimal-points-without-rounding-the-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i clicked on 'structure' in mysql table to see the field types etc, for 'menu_price', this field is having the data type 'decimal'.
Along with data type 'decimal', the next type is 'Length/Values'.

> The Length/Values was set to 15,3 and because of which i was getting 50.000 i.e. 3 digits after the decimal.

I changed it to 15,2. So now the value for price is showing as `50.00`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
CAST(2229.999 AS DECIMAL(6,2)) to get a decimal with 2 decimal places
```