# PHP round shows incorrect number when decimal place is longer

Tags: php, rounding

Take the following code:

```
echo round(1215.49999);
```

The answer I get, is `1215`, which is what I want.

However, when you write this:

```
echo round(1215.499999999999999);
```

The answer I get is `1216`.

Is there any particular reason for this? I would like to end up with `1215` in both cases.

Comment: You can read here about  [floating point precision in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: 1215.76655 for this, will you still want it to be 1215?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo No. If it's anything less than 1215.5, then it should be rounded down.

Comment: Check it please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668628/truncate-float-numbers-with-php/12710283#12710283

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use built-in PHP functions as opposed to writing your own, you could use `bcdiv`.

You will need to have `bcmath` enabled in your php.ini file to use `bcmath` functions, this may already be enabled, but if not it should just be a case of including the following:

```
--enable-bcmath
```

**Example 1:**

```
echo bcdiv(1215.49999, 1, 2);
```

**Example 2:**

```
echo bcdiv(1215.499999999999999, 1, 2);
```

Both of the above examples will output `1215`.

**Sources:**

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9944052/3393100)

[Source 2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

[Source 3](https://board.phpbuilder.com/d/2114375-call-to-undefined-function-bcdiv)

Answer (score 1):

If the input 1215.499999999999999 is interpreted from php as a float, everything is too late to round. This number is then identical to 1215.5

a test:

```
var_dump(1215.499999999999999 === 1215.5); //bool(true)
```

If the input is to be rounded , bcmat must be used and the input as string.

```
$input = '1215.499999999999999';
echo bcadd($input,0.5,0);  //1215

$input = '1215.5000000000000000';
echo bcadd($input,0.5,0);  //1216
```