# How to stop decimals being rounded up or down using php

Tags: php

I am calculating a number which I use in another calculation. the problem is this number could be 67.9699 I want it to say 67.96 without rounding up or down just chop the other digits of.
I was hoping the floor function would do this like:

```
$num2 = floor(($num1/5)*100)/100;
```

How ever this is still rounding the number up to 67.97 is there a away to stop this.
Any help welcome

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667413/show-2-decimal-places-without-rounding-off

Comment: What, exactly, is `$num1` in your code? This seems like a floating-point imprecision error to me.

Comment: $num1 is a number pulled out of a database e.g.$num1 = $row_Record1['price']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working well for me, try this:

`echo floor(67.9699 * 100) / 100;`

[Demo Online](http://codepad.org/YW8nytXU)

By the way, `number_format()` rounds the number.

Comment: `100` can be gotten by using `pow(10, $amountOfDecimals)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num2 = substr($num2,0,5);
echo $num2;
```

If you want to use the number again as float

```
$num2 = floatval($num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use number_format();

[number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)