# Having trouble converting my decimal data type to just 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql

Need some help here. I'm trying to update a column in one of my tables to take the Spend amount from 1 column and divide it by 0.85 and display at with only 2 decimal places.  I have tried the `ROUND` function and I am currently using the `CAST` function to list the field as a `DECIMAL` in which I've tried (38,2), (30,2), etc. and none work.  Here's a copy of what I'm trying to do :

```
(CAST(NetMediaSpend as decimal (38,2)))/.85
```

and even after I run it and look at my data I still see the value stored as :

```
13712.941176
```

How do I get it to only display 2 decimals of 13712.94 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format numbers to have only two decimal places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992406/how-do-i-format-numbers-to-have-only-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out how I needed to write it:

ROUND(CAST(NetMediaSpend as DECIMAL(30,2))/.85,2)

Answer (score 1):

```
CAST(NetMediaSpend / .85 AS DECIMAL(38,2))
```

Comment: or `ROUND(NetMediaSpend/.85,2)`, if NetMediaSpend is already defined as DECIMAL.

Comment: NetMediaSpend is defined as a float.....im trying to convert it to decimal and have it round to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

```
select format(NetMediaSpend/.85,2) from your_Table
```

Comment: Note that the introduction of the comma separators will cause an issue if the value is being assigned to a numeric column.