# Getting answer to 2 decimal places in php

Tags: php

I am adding 2 prices together (which are session variables) in php and I want it to show 2 decimal places. The session variables themselves show as 2 decimal places but when added together and for example the result is 2.50 only 2.5 is displayed. Is their a way I can display the two decimal places? This is the code I am using

```
 <div id="info">
  <span class="bluetext2">Total:&nbsp;</span>$<?php echo $_SESSION['startingPrice'] + $_SESSION['postage']; ?><br>
 </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format numbers to have only two decimal places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992406/how-do-i-format-numbers-to-have-only-two-decimal-places)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of options here.

[number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) - will output the decimal places, can also be used to specify a decimal point character as well as a thousands separator.

```
echo number_format($x, 2);
```

[printf/sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) - These are identical except that printf output whereas sprintf returns

```
printf('%.2f', $x);
echo sprintf('%.2f', $x);
```

[money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) - Locale aware money formater, will use the proper decimal and thousands separators based on locale.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
echo money_format("%i", $x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$Total = number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `echo number_format("2.5",2);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `number_format` function. This code:

```
echo number_format(12345.1, 2, ".","");
```

will give result: 12345.10

Also you can use short version:

```
number_format(12345.1, 2)
```

which results in 12,345.10 (I think that is english format ... )

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as -**
if u store that as an integer 
like $total=5.5000 at the time of displaying it will display 5.5. 
If u use is as $total="5.5000" then it will display as 5.5000

OR

$asdf=$x+$y; //5=2.50+2.50
echo number_format($asdf,2);

Comment: Isn't it string now? I think, you cant do `"2.5" + "3.5"`, but I can be mistaken ...

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate to
[PHP: show a number to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483540/php-show-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Use `number_format((float('number to be rounded off'),'` number of decimal places to be rounded off','separator between the whole number and the number after the separator')

example

```
$foo = 150
echo number_format(float($foo),2,'.')
```

will give 150.00