# Remove trailing zeroes in mysql (need exact query example)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, trailing

Good evening. I am trying to remove trailing zeroes from mysql data that is displayed in a table (pic.1).

[fragment of table (russian)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDLWC.png)

My code for the query is pretty much standard:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM t_transport";
$result = mysql_query($query);


while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['driver']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['sortiment']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['amount']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['origin']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['destination']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['tours']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['notes']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['ts']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

The column with the numbers is the 'amount' one. Data is stored as decimal(10,3). Need to remove trailing zeroes, if such appear.

Now I understand, that there have been many solutions to this, I've read them all, but none of them works for me. Please help me altering my query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Here you go, comrade:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149129/how-to-strip-trailing-zeros-in-php (PHP solution)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) in php for this formatting task.

```
echo "<td>" . number_format( $row['amount'], 0, '.', '' ) . "</td>";
```

Here's a more complete q&a on stack overflow:  [How do I format numbers to have only two decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992406/how-do-i-format-numbers-to-have-only-two-decimal-places)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But doesn't this just displays decimal values as whole numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * (CAST(`amount` AS CHAR)+0) as amountWOzero FROM t_transport";
```

You need to replace amount by the column with the trailing zeros and add amountWOzero to the php loop.